# How to solve the dimension mismatch between the training and test set loaded from svmlight format?

Tags: scikit-learn

```
X_train, y_train = load_svmlight_file(train_file)
X_test,y_test=load_svmlight_file(predict_file)
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y=clf.predict(X_test)
```

This is my code for the linear regression. My data is loaded from the svmlight format,which is like `label <id1>:<value1> <id2>:<value2> <id2>:<value2>`. But the problem is this is a sparse matrix. After I use `X_train.todense()` and `X_test.todense()`. The shape of `X_train` is 92*100 but `X_test` is 51*20. In fact the there both should have 92 dimension. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the number of features

```
X_test,y_test=load_svmlight_file(predict_file, n_features=92)
```

or use [`load_svmlight_files`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_files.html) which loads dataset from multiple files. In this case, if `n_features` is `None`, it will be inferred from the maximum column index occurring in any of the files.

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_svmlight_files((train_file, predict_file))
```